# Implement ngClick in angular-deckgrid?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement ngClick event in angular-deckgrid. 
As per their [documentation](https://github.com/akoenig/angular-deckgrid#scope), I have implemented the same, but all in vain. The Click is not being fired. I am using angular UI router states to provide the data to my view.

Below is the code snippet

```
<button name="left" data-ng-click="mother.left()">Left</button>
<button name="right" data-ng-click="mother.right()">Right</button>
```

In my state of my UI router,

```
sample.left=function(){
    alert('Left');
}
```

But this alert is never fired. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

a small mistake has caused the error. Specify "mother.sample.left()" on data-ng-click. Then it worked fine.